# dhcpd is listening on random port

Tags: server, dhcp, bug-reporting

I install a server ubuntu 18.04 LTS
and install isc-dhcp-server by

```
apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

find dhcpd is listening two more on random port

```
netstat -tplnu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1270/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1270/sshd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38147           0.0.0.0:*                           2447/dhcpd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           2447/dhcpd          
udp6       0      0 :::63082                :::*                                2447/dhcpd
```

I google it and find it a bug on this link here.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712503

it says  Fixed in version isc-dhcp/4.3.3-2

but where can I find the deb package in that version

the default version of isc-dhcp-server ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS is 4.3.5

and I only find the only version

```
apt-cache madison isc-dhcp-server
isc-dhcp-server | 4.3.5-3ubuntu7.1 | http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
isc-dhcp-server | 4.3.5-3ubuntu7.1 | http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
isc-dhcp-server | 4.3.5-3ubuntu7 | http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
  isc-dhcp | 4.3.5-3ubuntu7.1 | http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Sources
```

here is the ubuntu version

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS \n \l
```

I check the server ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

it has the same issue with the version of isc-dhcp-server 4.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Debian undid that modification as fix for [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798237).

You can either build from source, disabling NSUPDATE or use at least 4.3.6, since that's the [fixed upstream version](https://bugs.isc.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=45290).

Note that those ports are used for ddns, so if you have mentions to ddns in your config file, those ports will still be opened.